# How to set default ember cli proxy

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli, http-proxy

In order to proxy an ember-cli I do

```
ember s --proxy http://some.domain.com
```

Is there a way I can do `ember s` only and internally set some value so that proxy is always http://some.domain.com, I can always do --proxy to change the default proxy to something else

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Atlast I found a solution
In .ember-cli file in your app root folder add

```
{
  "proxy": "http://some.domain.com"
}
```

Works like a charm.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know that was even possible. Will save me so much time!!